# Porque CodeIgniter 3.1 rotas não funcionam?

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter-3

Eu sou iniciante em PHP, recentemente decidi aprender e comecei a ler o livro "CodeIgniter - Produtividade Na Criação de Aplicações Web Em PHP".
Na tentativa de seguir a criação de um site institucional, ao implementar um elemento **nav com uma ul(unorder list), cada li contém uma ancora**, tenho as minhas ancoras com o atributo

```
<a href="<?=base_url('empresa')?>" >A Empresa</a>
```

que carrega o base_url e concatena a rota 'empresa' - *Resta saber se está a funcionar*

**[diretórios do projecto]**

```
exemplos-livro-ci - site-institucional - application -
                                                   - cache
                                                   - config 
                                                   - controllers
                                                               - Institucional.php
                                                   - helpers 
                                                   - hooks
                                                   - language
                                                   - libraries
                                                   - logs
                                                   - models
                                                   - thirdparty
                                                   - views
                                      - assets(contém meus ficheiros css, js, img)
                                      - composer.json
                                      - .gitignore
                                      - .editorconfig
                                      - índex.php
                                      - license.txt
                                      - **web.config**
```

**[Código]**
*Controller*

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Institucional extends CI_Controller {
     public function index() {
        $data['title'] = "LCI | Home"; 
        $data['description'] = "Exercício de exemplo do capítulo 5 do livro CodeIgniter";
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
     }
     public function Empresa() {
        $data['title'] = "LCI | A Empresa"; 
        $data['description'] = "Informações sobre a empresa";
        $this->load->view('commons/header',$data); 
        $this->load->view('empresa'); 
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
     }
     public function Servicos() {
        $data['title'] = "LCI | Serviços"; 
        $data['description'] = "Informações sobre os serviços prestados";
        $this->load->view('commons/header',$data); 
        $this->load->view('servicos');
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
     }
}
?>
```

**[Código]** *View*

```
<nav>
<?php if($this->router->fetch_class() == 'Institucional' && $this->router->fetch_method() == 'index'){?>
<ul class="nav masthead-nav">
<?php } else {?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php } ?>
<li class="<?=($this->router->fetch_class() == 'Institucional' && $this->router->fetch_method() == 'index') ? 'active' : null; ?>"><a href="<?=base_url()?>" >Home</a></li> 
<li class="<?=($this->router->fetch_class() == 'Institucional' && $this->router->fetch_method() == 'Empresa') ? 'active' : null; ?>" ><a href="<?=base_url('empresa')?>" >A Empresa</a></li> 
<li class="<?=($this->router->fetch_class() == 'Institucional' && $this->router->fetch_method() == 'Servicos') ? 'active' : null; ?> "><a href="<?=base_url('servicos')?>" >Serviços</a></li> 
<li><a href="<?=base_url('trabalhe-conosco')?>">Trabalhe Conosco</a></li> 
<li><a href="<?=base_url('fale-conosco')?>">Fale Conosco</a></li> 
</ul>
</nav>
```

**[Propriedades]** application\config\config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/exemplos-livro-ci/site-institucional';
```

**[Propriedades]** application\config\routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Institucional';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['empresa'] = "application/controllers/Institucional/Empresa";
$route['servicos'] = "application/controllers/Institucional/Servicos";
```

**[Tentativas de debbug]** - Quando acedo ao meu índex com o url http://localhost/exemplos-livro-ci/site-institucional o browser exibe a minha HOME PAGE corretamente. Quando clico numa das ancoras( elemento), tenho o erro **404 - A URL requisitada não foi encontrada neste servidor**.
Quando pesquiso o caminho completo sem recurso á minha route(http://http://localhost/exemplos-livro-ci/site-institucional/application/controllers/Institucional/servicos) tenho o erro **403 - Você não tem permissão para acessar o objeto requisitado**

**[Á procura de informações]** - Seria interessante para o melhoramento do debbuging, conhecer se as rotas estão a ser atribuídas. Como faço isso? Talvez através do controller passar $data para a view e fazer display?.

Tecnologias utilizadas.
xampp v3.2.2.
Codeigniter v3.1.10
php v3.6.40

Answer (score -1):

Na raiz do projeto, criar um *.htaccess* com as linhas abaixo:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

E nas rotas as configurações deve ser sem (`application/controllers/`), como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$route['empresa'] = "Institucional/Empresa";
$route['servicos'] = "Institucional/Servicos";
```